# get max from table where sum required

Tags: sql-server, sum, max

Suppose I have a table with following data:

```
gameId  difficultyLevel  numberOfQuestions
--------------------------------------------
1           1                 2
1           2                 2
1           3                 1
```

In this example the game is configured for 5 questions, but I'm looking for a SQL statement that will work for *n* number of questions.

What I need is a SQL statement that given a question, `displayOrder` will return the current difficulty level of question.  For example - given a displayOrder of 3, with the table data above, will return 2.

Can anyone advise how the query should look like?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit.  Why does displayOrder 3 return 2?  What do you mean by displayOrder (presumably you would use ROW_NUMBER() with an ORDER BY, but what is the order?) and where does the 2 come from?

Comment: Let me try and clarify:
DisplayOrser mean gameQuestionNumber. DisplayOrser equals 3 mean return appropriate difficultyLevel, in this case 2 cause according to the table data first 2 questions from difficultyLevel 1, next 2 from difficultyLevel 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

things might be easier for you if you change your design as duffymo suggests, but if you must do it that way, here's a query that should do the trick.

```
SELECT MIN(difficultyLevel) as difficltyLevel
FROM 
(
    SELECT difficltyLevel, (SELECT sum(numberOfQuestions) FROM yourtable sub WHERE sub.difficultyLevel <= yt.difficultyLevel ) AS questionTotal
    FROM yourTable yt
) AS innerSQL
WHERE innerSQL.questionTotal >= @displayOrder
```

Comment: I tried your solution but got:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'questionTotal'.

Comment: Dan it does not return the right value.
The difficltyLevel must be with regard to input @displayOrder. Your query returns 1 when it should return 2.

Comment: @erez oops I forgot the where clause in the subquery.  It should be fixed now

Comment: @Dan That's exactly what I needed.
Thank you very much, your help is much Appreciated!
Erez

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a game table with a 1:m relationship with a question table.

You shouldn't repeat columns in a table - it violates first normal form.

Something like this:

```
create table if not exists game
(   
    game_id bigint not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    description varchar(64),
    primary key (game_id)    
);

create table if not exists question
(   
    question_id bigint not null auto_increment,
    text varchar(64),
    difficulty int default 1,
    game_id bigint,
    primary key (question_id)    ,
    foreign key game_id references game(game_id)
);

select 
game.game_id, name, description, question_id, text, difficulty
game left join question
on game.game_id = question.game_id
order by question_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @duffymo. I can not change the design right now.